# Haskell FFI for pdflib

Tags: haskell, ffi

I am trying to write ffi for pdflib library ( pdflib.com ) using c2hs on 64 linux.
You can download pdflib from their website for free (fully functional eval.)

I tried to compile and run their hello.c demo program and it works fine.

As far as i understand i need only 2 files to make it work: pdflib.h and libpdf.a

So i put both of them into hello folder, wrote a chs file, it compiles and generates hs file fine.
But when i try to compile my Hello.hs program cabal complains

Cabal: Missing dependency on a foreign library:
* Missing C library: pdflib

I tried giving it the folder name via --extra-include-dirs and --extra-lib-dirs but it does not help.

How do i compile haskell program with pdflib.h and libpdf.a files ?

Comment: first: I assume you've got  "extra-libraries: pdf" like in your cabal file? You need to make sure the name matches precisely (i.e. is the same as the library file but without the 'lib' prefix). second, i've had mixed results with .a files, probably through my own ignorance, but always had success with .so files.

Comment: Thanks! That did help. I did not know that i need to remove the "lib" prefix. Now i get bunch of other errors, but that's a different story (gcc, makefiles, g++)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Migrated from a comment to an answer:

first: I assume you've got "extra-libraries: pdf" like in your cabal file? You need to make sure the name matches precisely (i.e. is the same as the library file but without the 'lib' prefix). second, i've had mixed results with .a files, probably through my own ignorance, but always had success with .so files. – sclv 19 hours ago

Comment: Is there a way to convert .a file to .so file ? How do you work with .so files from haskell ? Do they require .h files as well ? Can i use the same .h file that comes with .a file ? Pdflib site has download bundles for different languages, including java, perl, python and php. Interestingly all of them include specially made .so files, like pdflib_java.so, pdflib_py.so etc. But no header file included. Is there a way to peek inside .so files like in windows there are utilities that allow you to look inside dlls.

Comment: .a files are statically linked libraries, .so files are dynamic. If cabal is finding the .a file, you should brobably be fine -- I'm no expert though. I'd expect your other problems aren't necessarily related to the choice of a static/dynamic lib -- I'd actually had problems getting cabal to even find .a as opposed to .so files before.

Comment: Pdflib readme says to use g++ instead of gcc when compiling with .a file. I am not sure what cabal or ghc use. At this point i'd just have to drop it cause i have neither time not expertise in this area.

Comment: @Vagif Well, that's your problem then. GHC can't generally bind to C++ libraries directly.  You need to wrap the calls to the C++ lib in a C lib that you write, and then use that. I'm told this is a royal pain.

Answer (score 0):

The linker will need to be able to find your .a file. It will look in the usual /usr/lib paths. Can you install pdflib into the regular system locations (e.g. via your package manager)? This will be the easiest path.

Comment: Is there a way to just tell it where the file is ? And i tried to put it in the same folder as hs files.

Comment: I tried to copy libpdf.a to /usr/lib. Cabal still does not see it

Comment: Ingo: It was weird usage of cabal option, that requires to drop "lib" prefix. I did not know that. And yes, i downloaded 64 bit version, and it compiles and runs fine when trying their hello.c example.